# getState() in redux giving different userId in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

In my app, I am trying to add a new product that uses getState().userId as a key so that If I use the same email I will see that added product in my admin section but sometimes, I am not able to add product, and my app giving me an error saying: `VirtualizedList: missing keys for items, make sure to specify a key or id property on each item or provide a custom keyExtractor`.

So, for debugging purposes, I checked the getState.userId I am getting and I get different userId from redux that's why I can't see my product in my admin area as I have added their `ownerId===userId`.

But, After reloading or refreshing the app, I am able to see my product there and also able to add product with the correct userId on firebase.

store/action/Auth.js:

```
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";

let timer;

export const AUTHENTICATE = "AUTHENTICATE";
export const LOGOUT = "LOGOUT";

export const Authenticate = (userId, token, expiryTime) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(setLogoutTimer(expiryTime));
    dispatch({ type: AUTHENTICATE, userId: userId, token: token });
  };
};

export const signup = (email, password) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=AIzaSyAnaJyjjGppk9-FiWocva_cP0vaMrKp4_4",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email: email,
          password: password,
          returnSecureToken: true,
        }),
      }
    );
    if (!response.ok) {
      const responseData = await response.json();
      const errorMessage = responseData.error.message;
      if (errorMessage === "EMAIL_EXISTS") {
        throw new Error("Email already exists");
      }
    }
    const resData = await response.json();
    console.log(resData);
    dispatch(
      Authenticate(
        resData.idToken,
        resData.localId,
        parseInt(resData.expiresIn) * 1000
      )
    );
    const expirationDate = new Date(
      new Date().getTime() + parseInt(resData.expiresIn) * 1000
    );
    saveDataToStorage(resData.idToken, resData.localId, expirationDate);
  };
};

export const login = (email, password) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=AIzaSyAnaJyjjGppk9-FiWocva_cP0vaMrKp4_4",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email: email,
          password: password,
          returnSecureToken: true,
        }),
      }
    );
    if (!response.ok) {
      const responseData = await response.json();
      const errorMessage = responseData.error.message;
      if (
        errorMessage === "EMAIL_NOT_FOUND" ||
        errorMessage === "INVALID_PASSWORD"
      ) {
        throw new Error("Email or Password is wrong!!");
      }
    }
    const resData = await response.json();
    console.log(resData);
    dispatch(
      Authenticate(
        resData.idToken,
        resData.localId,
        parseInt(resData.expiresIn) * 1000
      )
    );
    const expirtationDate = new Date(
      new Date().getTime() + parseInt(resData.expiresIn) * 1000
    );
    saveDataToStorage(resData.idToken, resData.localId, expirtationDate);
  };
};

export const logout = () => {
  clearLogoutTimer();
  AsyncStorage.removeItem("userData");
  return { type: LOGOUT };
};

const clearLogoutTimer = () => {
  if (timer) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }
};

const setLogoutTimer = (expirationTime) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch(logout());
    }, expirationTime);
  };
};

const saveDataToStorage = (token, userId, expirtationDate) => {
  AsyncStorage.setItem(
    "userData",
    JSON.stringify({
      token: token,
      userId: userId,
      expiryDate: expirtationDate.toISOString(),
    })
  );
};
```

store/action/product.js:

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import Product from "../../models/Product";

export const CREATE_PRODUCT = "CREATE_PRODUCT";
export const SET_PRODUCT = "SET_PRODUCT";

export const fetchProducts = () => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const userId = getState().Auth.userId;
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://shopping-app-62e38-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/products.json"
      );

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Something went wrong!");
      }

      const resData = await response.json();
      const loadedProducts = [];

      for (const key in resData) {
        loadedProducts.push(
          new Product(
            key,
            resData[key].ownerId,
            resData[key].title,
            resData[key].imageUrl,
            resData[key].description,
            resData[key].price
          )
        );
      }
      dispatch({
        type: SET_PRODUCT,
        products: loadedProducts,
        userProducts: loadedProducts.filter((prod) => prod.ownerId === userId),
      });
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  };
};


export const createProduct = (title, description, imageUrl, price) => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const token = getState().Auth.token;
    const userId = getState().Auth.userId;
    console.log(getState());
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://shopping-app-62e38-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/products.json?auth=${token}`,
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          title,
          description,
          imageUrl,
          price,
          ownerId: userId,
        }),
      }
    );
    const resData = await response.json();
    console.log(userId);

    dispatch({
      type: CREATE_PRODUCT,
      productData: {
        id: resData.name,
        title,
        description,
        imageUrl,
        price,
        ownerId: userId,
      },
    });
  };
};
```

I tried adding a product. But I got same error mentioned above.

console.log()- getState() :

```
"Auth": Object {
    "token": "9WwCUWtUeDaeHPHfURuBMSAaT553",
    "userId": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjFiYjk2MDVjMzZlOThlMzAxMTdhNjk1MTc1NjkzODY4MzAyMDJiMmQiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NlY3VyZXRva2VuLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vc2hvcHBpbmctYXBwLTYyZTM4IiwiYXVkIjoic2hvcHBpbmctYXBwLTYyZTM4IiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoxNjI3MDY5NTM1LCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiOVd3Q1VXdFVlRGFlSFBIZlVSdUJNU0FhVDU1MyIsInN1YiI6IjlXd0NVV3RVZURhZUhQSGZVUnVCTVNBYVQ1NTMiLCJpYXQiOjE2MjcwNjk1MzUsImV4cCI6MTYyNzA3MzEzNSwiZW1haWwiOiJ0ZXN0QGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImVtYWlsX3ZlcmlmaWVkIjpmYWxzZSwiZmlyZWJhc2UiOnsiaWRlbnRpdGllcyI6eyJlbWFpbCI6WyJ0ZXN0QGdtYWlsLmNvbSJdfSwic2lnbl9pbl9wcm92aWRlciI6InBhc3N3b3JkIn19.Yq2CjY7anrwuQSt2N5nMSa3vUKh1gFiIuyO1Mw4-WQwbf_y9b9IYOHSG1YkXgFoyONOV71DOlT9JmWzGu9g2aFSKKUU3LffTY5WNQd5-Qm9QdbhHB0CtOAPJZ124FKiLLS0wJh0nVZKez8_6dH2ICOCw3e-lyktHOc6R11s_9xhEF1LLYv20b7BziWy6T_VHZOcUsiJbBwn09lx1SKkK4Ic3iEsWNeg-lSAgPJGO-sClUmwW9ffA3L1p8OvZubSNirKcGbRYkC323wXnlWv-tqqj6CW-uNc448i6qsmrs2RRR_f4WdLFN9dvv_PBjsf7V8r0m_HY4jjDzScNLLA4Hg",
  },
  "cart": Object {
    "items": Object {},
    "totalAmount": 0,
  },
  "orders": Object {
    "orders": Array [],
  },
  "products": Object {
    "availableProducts": Array [
      Product {
        "description": "Apple Macbook Air M1 chip",
        "id": "-Md76UnJ1I1lNhGgldH3",
        "imageUrl": "https://www.zdnet.com/a/hub/i/r/2020/11/23/77824151-c578-4431-8f00-633b1b7c0b99/thumbnail/770x433/3b5a2366cdeef2dc08730041abdcf426/macbook-air-m1-header.jpg",
        "ownerId": undefined,
        "price": 1200,
        "title": "Macbook Air M1 2020",
      },
      Product {
        "description": "Apple · iPhone 64GB Blue· iPhone 12 mini · iOS · 5.4 inches screen · Facial Recognition · 12 MP Front Camera · 12 MP Rear Camera · Smartphone · Wireless Charging",
        "id": "-Mekel4gfFtgNUviidau",
        "imageUrl": "https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/shopping?q=tbn:ANd9GcS_WPpNagW5q_-KAep1QkiInHfUYADs8qv84Z_FqKwMmW-J7nleMbl5y6muot5dxxRCOBZ-S_dYxxp_QpmTqzSnTj9oKQuH84kSCYjAZXT6UIsrnWJowbMMLw&usqp=CAE",
        "ownerId": "9WwCUWtUeDaeHPHfURuBMSAaT553",
        "price": 956.99,
        "title": "Apple iPhone 12 Mini",
      },
    ],
    "userProducts": Array [],
  },
}
```

console.log()-userID:

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjFiYjk2MDVjMzZlOThlMzAxMTdhNjk1MTc1NjkzODY4MzAyMDJiMmQiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NlY3VyZXRva2VuLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vc2hvcHBpbmctYXBwLTYyZTM4IiwiYXVkIjoic2hvcHBpbmctYXBwLTYyZTM4IiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoxNjI3MDY5NTM1LCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiOVd3Q1VXdFVlRGFlSFBIZlVSdUJNU0FhVDU1MyIsInN1YiI6IjlXd0NVV3RVZURhZUhQSGZVUnVCTVNBYVQ1NTMiLCJpYXQiOjE2MjcwNjk1MzUsImV4cCI6MTYyNzA3MzEzNSwiZW1haWwiOiJ0ZXN0QGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImVtYWlsX3ZlcmlmaWVkIjpmYWxzZSwiZmlyZWJhc2UiOnsiaWRlbnRpdGllcyI6eyJlbWFpbCI6WyJ0ZXN0QGdtYWlsLmNvbSJdfSwic2lnbl9pbl9wcm92aWRlciI6InBhc3N3b3JkIn19.Yq2CjY7anrwuQSt2N5nMSa3vUKh1gFiIuyO1Mw4-WQwbf_y9b9IYOHSG1YkXgFoyONOV71DOlT9JmWzGu9g2aFSKKUU3LffTY5WNQd5-Qm9QdbhHB0CtOAPJZ124FKiLLS0wJh0nVZKez8_6dH2ICOCw3e-lyktHOc6R11s_9xhEF1LLYv20b7BziWy6T_VHZOcUsiJbBwn09lx1SKkK4Ic3iEsWNeg-lSAgPJGO-sClUmwW9ffA3L1p8OvZubSNirKcGbRYkC323wXnlWv-tqqj6CW-uNc448i6qsmrs2RRR_f4WdLFN9dvv_PBjsf7V8r0m_HY4jjDzScNLLA4Hg
```

After some refresh or log in again, I am able to see my product added before and which was already on firebase now fetched from and shown on admin area as I am getting correct userId from getState().

Note: The product I tried above is not added but some products I already added and which were not fetched as userId I am getting is incorrect.

When I am getting the correct userId from firebase which is also my ownerId then I am able to see my product in my admin area.

**I am getting idToken in userId instead of localId. I don't know why and how to solve this.**

Comment: If your state's `userId` is wrong, perhaps show the place(s) where it's set? Unless that's not the issue, in which case I'd say make your question clearer. If your state's `userId` is actually always correct, then perhaps check your Firebase setup?

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs check now. I have added the Auth.js file in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue seems to be your `Authenticate` part:

```js
// When defining Authenticate
export const Authenticate = (userId, token, expiryTime) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(setLogoutTimer(expiryTime));
    dispatch({ type: AUTHENTICATE, userId: userId, token: token });
  };
};

// In your signup and login
    dispatch(
      Authenticate(
        resData.idToken,
        resData.localId,
        parseInt(resData.expiresIn) * 1000
      )
    );
```

You're passing the arguments in the wrong order, which would explain why your userId/localId is your token and vice versa.

Comment: I didn't get it. What you have changed in the code? Everything you have mentioned is the same in my code. Please have a look on my code once again.

Comment: @HarshMishra I just copied the parts of your code that's wrong. Notice how the top half uses `(userId, token, expiryTime)` while in the bottom half you call it with `(resData.idToken, resData.localId, ...)`? Looks like the wrong order to me.

Comment: But I have defined `resData` just above it. And, `token, userId` I am getting from my state. And, the code you have written is already present in my code. What should I change then?

Comment: @HarshMishra Do you see how you defined `Authenticate` as expecting `(userId, token, expiryTime)` but instead you're doing `dispatch(Authenticate(resData.idToken, resData.localId, ...))`? I think you swapped the `resData.idToken` and `resData.localId` around.

Comment: Oh. Okay. I got it. I was really swapping the values by mistake. Now, I am getting the correct values. Thanks a lot for your help.